# Refrigerator fiberglass exposure

Tags: refrigerator

The plastic piece that covers the door of the refrigerator broke off and is exposing the fiberglass underneath. Is this a health hazard???
How can this be fixed or should I just get a new one???

Answer (score 2):

The fiberglass itself is not really a serious hazard like asbestos would be, unless it gets into your food or on containers. Not a good idea to have exposed fiberglass near your food however.  You should seal the hole with duct tape or something to keep the fiberglass from getting on your stuff.  If the missing piece of door is too big or you can't confine the fiberglass,  you should consider getting a new fridge ASAP.